# How would I compile a .sass without watching the file

Tags: sass

I'd like to decide when a `.sass` file is compiled. In other words, I don't want to *watch* the file but compile manually.

**How would I do that?**

Comment: Why do you want to do it manually ? I mean can you be more explicit about your needs ?

Comment: It's used for a build tool. So, I want to have the compiler only start when I want it to. Not on every file change.

Comment: Thanks for the downvote! Care to explain?

Comment: upvoted because this question helped me.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It was simpler than I thought:

```
sass style.scss style.css
```

Comment: Oh you are gooing to do this for each files? Manually?

Comment: Nope. Just one file and only in certain occasions.

Comment: Oh ok, then why not watching the file when needed?

Comment: If I watch the file, then every change leads to a compilation. I don't want that.

Answer (score 0):

You should have a look to Sassifier, it's a standalone compiler for Sass made to be used as a third party compiler https://github.com/zaus/Sassifier

I don"t know if it fits every side of your needs, but it's opensource so you cade fork it and tweak it :)

Comment: Thanks. I was complicating things too much. :)