# what's wrong with my svg code?

Tags: html, css, svg

This code only works in codepen but jsfiddle, please tell me what's wrong with my code. [FULL CODE LINK](https://jsfiddle.net/nojava/gs85ete1/)

```
<svg width="500px" height="20px" viewBox="0 0 561 10" >
<line class="path" fill="none" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" x1="0"   y1="0" x2="561" y2="0"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: Press the "css" button in the top right corner. Choose "SCSS"

Comment: You cannot use variables in CSS. `$line-offset: 350;`

Comment: how do I use "scss" in normal webpage?

Comment: You compile it to css first. The webpage still only uses css. There are many ways to do this and that is outside the scope of this question. Check out [posts like this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19047384/how-would-i-compile-a-sass-without-watching-the-file) for more info

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to change the `css` to `scss` in the top right corner, because in your `css` part appers features that don't exist in CSS yet;

> Scss lets you use features that don't exist in CSS yet like variables,
>   nesting, inheritance, etc

Here is [working solution](https://jsfiddle.net/ionutmihai1995/gs85ete1/2/)

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [**it would be preferable**](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes

Comment: can I achieve this animation without using scss? blog doesn't have scss files in its architecture,  what should I do then?

Comment: @X.L, scss compiles to css, so you can do it with css easily. You can use a website like http://www.sassmeister.com/ to compile your scss code to css

Comment: @MaximePeloquin thanks mate the compiling web works great!